# Extract text and integer after specific letter

Tags: python, regex, list, split, integer

I have string:

```
s = 'travel to africa x 2\ asia x 2\ europe x 2\ Airport pick up included. Furnitures 3 seater couch x 1 4 seater+ couch x 1 < 60 inches TV x 1 60 inches+ TV x 1 Washer - front loader x 1 Box / bag / misc x 1 The maximum clearance is 1.5m.'
```

I would like split it by `x` and extract number after it.

So expected output is:

```
out = [('travel to africa', '2'),
       ('\ asia', '2'),
       ( '\ europe', '2'),
       ('\ Airport pick up included. Furnitures 3 seater couch', '1'),
       ('4 seater+ couch', '1'),
       ('< 60 inches TV', '1'),
       ('60 inches+ TV', '1'),
       ('Washer - front loader', '1'),
       ('Box / bag / misc', '1')]
```

I try this regex, but failed, because special chars like `-+<` was omited (also there should be another special chars):

```
r'([A-Za-z 0-9]+)\s+x\s+(\d+)'
```

What is correct regex for extract this values? Or also is possible solution without regex?

Comment: You are not splitting, but extracting, try `re.findall(r'(.*?)\s+x\s*(\d+)', s)`, see https://ideone.com/fclZme

Comment: yes, but here is is series, in first all dataframe

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may use

```
re.findall(r'(.*?)\s+x\s*(\d+)', s)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/fclZme) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/d5Ws7o/1).

The `(.*?)\s+x\s*(\d+)` pattern matches

- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any 0+ chars other than line break chars
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `x` - `x` char
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(\d+)` - Group 2: one or more digits.

If you want to get rid of whitespace at the start of the match, use either `re.findall(r'(\S.*?)\s+x\s*(\d+)', s)` (see [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/d5Ws7o/2)) or use comprehension after getting all matches, `[x.strip() for x in re.findall(r'(.*?)\s+x\s*(\d+)', s)]`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it.I simplified the problem by just trying to match each group, and split manually afterwards.

```
s = 'travel to africa x 2\ asia x 2\ europe x 2\ Airport pick up included. Furnitures 3 seater couch x 1 4 seater+ couch x 1 < 60 inches TV x 1 60 inches+ TV x 1 Washer - front loader x 1 Box / bag / misc x 1 The maximum clearance is 1.5m.'
import re
res = []
for match in re.finditer(".*?x\s*\d+", s):
    l, _, r = map(str.strip, match.group().rpartition('x'))
    res.append((l, r))
```

Output:

```
[('travel to africa', '2'),
 ('\\ asia', '2'),
 ('\\ europe', '2'),
 ('\\ Airport pick up included. Furnitures 3 seater couch', '1'),
 ('4 seater+ couch', '1'),
 ('< 60 inches TV', '1'),
 ('60 inches+ TV', '1'),
 ('Washer - front loader', '1'),
 ('Box / bag / misc', '1')]
```

Answer (score 1):

My take on problem:

```
import re
import pprint

s = 'travel to africa x 2\ asia x 2\ europe x 2\ Airport pick up included. Furnitures 3 seater couch x 1 4 seater+ couch x 1 < 60 inches TV x 1 60 inches+ TV x 1 Washer - front loader x 1 Box / bag / misc x 1 The maximum clearance is 1.5m.'

out = []

for g in re.findall(r'(((^|\\?).*?)\s*x\s*(\d+)(.*?))', s):
    out += [[g[1], g[3]]]

pprint.pprint(out)
```

Prints:

```
[['travel to africa', '2'],
 ['\\ asia', '2'],
 ['\\ europe', '2'],
 ['\\ Airport pick up included. Furnitures 3 seater couch', '1'],
 [' 4 seater+ couch', '1'],
 [' < 60 inches TV', '1'],
 [' 60 inches+ TV', '1'],
 [' Washer - front loader', '1'],
 [' Box / bag / misc', '1']]
```